# Facebook graph api function - empty response

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, mobile, air

im currently working on facebook integration into my mobile AS3 game. I'am downloading friends pictures, which works just fine and is not currently an issue. Problem is, i am trying to detect, if user has silhouette (default) picture or his own (is_silhouette property);

Here goes code:

(response[i].id) is valid user id which i have got from previous api comunication

```
...
HasDefault(response[i].id);
...

    private function HasDefault(uid:int):void{
        FacebookMobile.api("/"+uid+"/picture", callbackX);
    }


    private function callbackX(response:Object,fail:Object):void{
    if (response != null){
      trace(response.url);
      trace(response.is_silhouette);
    }else{
      trace("here goes nothing...");
    }
```

first things first...this code above has 2 issues. First problem is, unless i use absolute URL, facebook does not respond, so API method has actually look like this:

```
FacebookMobile.api("https://graph.facebook.com/"+uid+"/picture", callbackX);
```

i dont know why i have to use absolute url here, because anywhere else id/function is good enough...but that is not still main problem.

If i use absolute URL i do get valid response from facebook but according to this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/ i should get response.url and response.is_silhouette in my response object. i however recieve only empty response object...I'am starting to be realy desperate.

In addition, i have tried to paste THE SAME request into the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer explorer and surprise surprise...it returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc1/somenumbers.jpg", 
    "is_silhouette": false
  }
}
```

...which is exactly what i need...but within the application i get only empty response object...

Comment: For edification, here's the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307115/facebook-graph-api-function-empty-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you line "FacebookMobile.api("https://graph.facebook.com/"+uid+"/picture", callbackX);" does. 
But whatever library that is, stop using it, because its not letting you specify the call you want to make. You can just call the graph api calls yourself using a URLLoader.

So here is the magical thing that is going wrong: You need to be able to append an extra variable when you request the picture: "?redirect=false"
This tells facebook to give you a json response. If you do not have that variable, you will get a redirect to the actual image, which is usually what a person wants anyway.
To see how that works, test out the two links below, one with redirect=false - which you want. and One with it set to true - which you do not.

https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?redirect=false

https://graph.facebook.com/shaverm/picture?redirect=true

I am pretty sure what is happening is that you are getting the image back instead of the json response describing the image.

Comment: I'll look into that. By the way FacebookMobile is official Adobe sdk for OpenGraph API ...

Comment: Ahh yes. That thing. Last updated October 2011?
https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/source/list
I think maybe time to discard it and switch to calling the graph directly.

Comment: you were right man, i tried to load it with redirect false through standart loader/request model and it worked like a charm, thanks. Yes, maybe it is, thanks for your advice